# How to make an object opaque in a 3D plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, mplot3d

So currently I'm plotting the path of a satellite around the earth over time. It's a 3 month mission, and I'm plotting one orbit of the satellite every 15 days to show how the orbit changes. Currently I have this code:

```
#######################################################################
    # 3-D Plotting (1 Orbit Done per 15 Days = 1,296,000 Seconds
                # 1,296,000 Seconds = 43,200 Data points
#######################################################################

time_step = 40320 # Data points in Fifteen Days
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

u = numpy.linspace(0, 2 * numpy.pi, 100)
v = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi, 100)

x_sphere = 1 * numpy.outer(numpy.cos(u), numpy.sin(v))
y_sphere = 1 * numpy.outer(numpy.sin(u), numpy.sin(v))
z_sphere = 1 * numpy.outer(numpy.ones(numpy.size(u)), numpy.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x_sphere, y_sphere, z_sphere,  rstride=1, cstride=1, color='white', linewidth=0, alpha=1.)

ax.set_xlabel('X axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z axis')

colors =     ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue','indigo','violet','pink','tan','teal','brown','gray','coral']

for num in range(2):
    x = numpy.transpose(x_coords_row_interp)[num*time_step:(num*time_step)+187] # One Period Every 93.47137682 Minutes (~186.943 half minutes)
    y = numpy.transpose(y_coords_row_interp)[num*time_step:(num*time_step)+187] # One Period Every 93.47137682 Minutes (~186.943 half minutes)
    z = numpy.transpose(z_coords_row_interp)[num*time_step:(num*time_step)+187] # One Period Every 93.47137682 Minutes (~186.943 half minutes)

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s=0)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
    while count < len(x)-1:
        ax.plot([x[count][0],x[count+1][0]],[y[count][0],y[count+1][0]],[z[count][0],z[count+1][0]],color = colors[num])
        count=count+1

    red = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="red")
    orange = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="orange")

    ax.legend([red,orange],['Zero Days','Fifteen Days'])

    ax.view_init(elev=20., azim=45)
```

Which yields this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXJGr.png

However, it is hard to decipher which side of the sphere the orbit is on due to the spheres transparency. How do I make the sphere opaque so that it is easier to visualize the path of the orbit?

Comment: `alpha` controls the level of transparency for your 3d plot. Try reducing it to 0.1 or so.

Comment: @ Nickil Maveli that makes the sphere more transparent. I want it to where I can't see the line on the other side of the sphere i.e opaque

Comment: Oops, you're right. Why not try setting `antialiased=False` which by the way minimizes the overlapping portions?

Comment: @ Nickil Maveli I tried it and it didn't look like it did anything significant. The orbit paths are still visible behind the sphere :/

Comment: Can you post the correct code especially after `for i in range(len(x)):`.. ? Then I can take a look at it.

Comment: My code is correct? What do you mean